# How can i run my statements from the terminal for Java?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command-line-arguments

How can i run my statements from the terminal?

```
$ java -c System.out.println("test");
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: This isn't something Java is suited for. Perhaps you're thinking of a dynamic interpreted language on the JVM, like BeanShell or Groovy;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), it is a dynamic **superset** of Java. Which means you can run any Java statement as a Groovy statement. It has an [interactive REPL shell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell) that can execute Java statements or Groovy statements equally as well.

You can also write scripts using plain Java statements as well, no need for Groovy syntax short cuts or extensions and run them as scripts.

```
groovy -e "println 'Hello ' + args[0]" World
```

Comment: Can you install it in packaged distro using #yum -y install groovy; yes or no can?

Answer (score 2):

Look up BeanShell!  It's not quite "pure" Java, but it's super close and really useful!  [www.beanshell.org](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need something professional, you can use simple shell script to wrap your statement in function and class body, compile and execute it.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "class Main\n{\npublic static void main(String[] args)\n{" > /tmp/Main.java
echo $* >> /tmp/Main.java
echo "\n}\n}\n" >> /tmp/Main.java

javac /tmp/Main.java || exit 1
exec java -cp /tmp/ Main
```